# Backbone.js data persistence

Tags: backbone.js, persistence, data-persistence

If I am building an application with backbone.js, what is the best tool or combo of tools to use for data persistence?

So I cannot answer my own question for another seven hours so I am throwing the answer in here:

I just found a great link to answer my own question. Exactly what I am looking for:
http://pixelhandler.com/blog/2012/02/09/develop-a-restful-api-using-node-js-with-express-and-mongoose/

Comment: Depends. Why don't you make use of all that extra space in the question box and tell us more about your problem?

Comment: It's a simple question. My apology for not expanding.

I come from the land of .NET where server side and client side are more standardized.

I recently made the move to a company who scrapes pages and uses backbone to parse the jsondata returned.

Do you have a solution that works for you? If so I would appreciate any help you can give. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something even simpler without the Mongoose dependency I've made a very short example on how to achieve basic persistence with Backbone, Express.js and MongoDB.

https://gist.github.com/1999230

Answer (score 1):

You can use StackMob. Check out the website (https://www.stackmob.com/)
I didn't use it a lot, but you can watch this great lecture at Udemy (http://www.udemy.com/learn-backbonejs-stackmob/), and watch the lecture 11 and 12

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a lot less coding, take a look at [Urbini](http://github.com/urbien/urbini%20Urbini).
It is like IFTTT, but more open as it allows you to create your own adapter to map any WebAPI into backbone models. Urbini provides seamless persistence to IndexedDB (with a fallback to WebSQL) and automatic sync with the web site via its WebAPI.